# Flutter: No implementation found for method getBatteryLevel on channel myChannel

Tags: flutter

I use MethodChannel to implement unlock screen to see coming calls.
When the emulator screen is on, my other method channels like getting batterylevel information is working, it works perfectly but when i lock the screen i begin getting error. My app gives: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getBatteryLevel on channel myChannel)

How can i activate the application methodchannels when the screen is off ?

Here is my codes:

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

import android.app.KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.content.Context;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "myChannel";

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler(
                        (call, result) -> {
                            if (call.method.equals("getBatteryLevel")) {
                                int batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel();

                                if (batteryLevel != -1) {
                                    result.success(batteryLevel);
                                } else {
                                    result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Battery level not available.", null);
                                }
                            } else {
                                result.notImplemented();
                            }
                        }
                );
    }

    private int getBatteryLevel() {
        int batteryLevel = -1;
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            BatteryManager batteryManager = (BatteryManager) getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE);
            batteryLevel = batteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext()).
                    registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
            batteryLevel = (intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) * 100) /
                    intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        }

        return batteryLevel;
    }
}
```

Dart:

```
const platform = const MethodChannel('myChannel');
Future<int> getBatteryLevel() async {
  int batteryLevel;
  try {
    batteryLevel = await platform.invokeMethod('getBatteryLevel');
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print("Error: '${e.message}'.");
    batteryLevel = -1; // Return -1 if there's an error
  }
  return batteryLevel;
}
```

AndroidManifest permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you lock your phone your app is suspended and cannot do any work in the background. For your App to resume without any user interaction/UI you need a service: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Also relevant:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76696